# Can someone help me decipher this query? Confusing case statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I'm having a hard time reading this query. I need to get rid of everything that has to do with "ShowStandadrdCost" so the outer most case. But I cant seem to figure out which exact lines to delete.

```
(CASE WHEN ISNULL(ShowStandardCost, 0) = 0 THEN
                CASE WHEN ISNULL(s.Actual_Cost, 0) = 0
                        THEN ISNULL(s.Standard_Cost, 0)
                        ELSE s.Actual_Cost  
                END
             ELSE ISNULL(s.Standard_Cost, 0)
        END + (CASE WHEN ISNULL(ShowStandardCost, 0) = 0 THEN
                CASE WHEN ISNULL(s.Actual_Cost, 0) = 0
                        THEN ISNULL(s.Standard_Cost, 0)
                        ELSE s.Actual_Cost  
                END
             ELSE ISNULL(s.Standard_Cost, 0)
        END ) Item_Cost_Per,
```

Is the whole query just

```
CASE WHEN ISNULL(s.Actual_Cost, 0) = 0
                            THEN ISNULL(s.Standard_Cost, 0)
                            ELSE s.Actual_Cost
```

What is being added I can't tell.

Comment: `CASE` expression, not statement. A `CASE` expression and `CASE` statement are very different, and SQL Server does not support the latter.

Comment: Not sure I understand what your asking here, are you simply asking us to explain what the first snippet of a query is doing? What parts do you, or don't you understand?

Comment: I understand that the core of the query is that if actual cost is null, use standard cost (I think) but I don't understand what all these case statements are doing.

Comment: Some sample data might be helpful too.

Comment: Here is how i'm reading the query. When ShowStandCost is null, then use actual cost unless it's null, then use standard cost. When show standard cost is not null, use standard cost. And then it multiplying that number by two? (adding it to itself) Am I correct?

Comment: So would this be the simplified version without ShowStandardCost ?

(CASE
         WHEN
            ISNULL(s.Actual_Cost, 0) = 0 
         THEN
            ISNULL(s.Standard_Cost, 0) 
         ELSE
            s.Actual_Cost ) Item_Cost_Per

But it's telling me it's wrong.

Comment: Honestly, if I'm reading it correctly, the query could be written as `ISNULL(ISNULL(NULLIF(ShowStandardCost,0),ISNULL(NULLIF(s.Actual_Cost,0),s.Standard_Cost)),0) * 2` (not that they may be easier to read). Not sure why the expression is adding itself to itself, but that's what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably how I would write the expression.

```
CASE WHEN ShowStandardCost <> 0 --Maybe (ShowStandardCost = 1)?
    THEN ISNULL(s.Standard_Cost, 0)
    ELSE --Show Actual Cost, unless it's zero or null. 
         --If so, show Standard_Cost unless it's null. 
         --Only show zero if both columns are zero or null.
        COALESCE( NULLIF( s.Actual_Cost, 0), s.Standard_Cost, 0)
    END * 2 --The CASE expression is just repeating itself.
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, not sure if you want this,

```
CASE WHEN ISNULL(s.Actual_Cost, 0) = 0 THEN ISNULL(s.Standard_Cost, 0) ELSE s.Actual_Cost end Item_Cost_Per
```

Actual query commented below,

```
/*(CASE WHEN ISNULL(ShowStandardCost, 0) = 0 THEN */
                CASE WHEN ISNULL(s.Actual_Cost, 0) = 0
                        THEN ISNULL(s.Standard_Cost, 0)
                        ELSE s.Actual_Cost  
                END
            /* ELSE ISNULL(s.Standard_Cost, 0)
        END + (CASE WHEN ISNULL(ShowStandardCost, 0) = 0 THEN
                CASE WHEN ISNULL(s.Actual_Cost, 0) = 0
                        THEN ISNULL(s.Standard_Cost, 0)
                        ELSE s.Actual_Cost  
                END
             ELSE ISNULL(s.Standard_Cost, 0)
        END ) */ Item_Cost_Per,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If ShowStandardCost = null Then
   If Actual_Cost =  null Then
       If Standard_Cost = null Then 0 Else Standard_Cost
   Else Actual_Cost
End
```

Then the statement repeats and adds that value to itself.  I'd just surround the first part with parens and add "* 2" at the end if was me.

```
(CASE WHEN ISNULL(ShowStandardCost, 0) = 0 THEN
         CASE WHEN ISNULL(s.Actual_Cost, 0) = 0
                THEN ISNULL(s.Standard_Cost, 0)
                ELSE s.Actual_Cost  
         END
      ELSE ISNULL(s.Standard_Cost, 0)
  END) * 2
```